# Filter output written by tee to file, but not output written by tee to console

Tags: python, bash, tee

I know similar questions have been asked, but I've been unable to find anything that addresses this particular situation.

I have a series of different python scripts that are using the `logging` library (which prints to `stderr`). These scripts are strung together by a bash script, which calls them sequentially and is scheduled via `cron`. At the end of each run, the bash script emails a summary of the various exit codes and is intended to contain various other logging messages (i.e., if there is a `critical` level logging occurrence, it should make it to what I'm calling the "cron log").

Since the python code itself is quite verbose in its logging, I don't want to accidentally email myself a 5-10MB log, and I only want specific output to make it to the cron log. I want to use `tee` to filter the `stderr` logging from python, and only direct *particular* messages to the cron log, but *all* messages should still make it to the console.

For reproducibility, say I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGPFX="BASH"  # if a log msg has this term, put it in CRONLOG
CRONLOG="cronlog.txt"

exec 2> >(grep ${LOGPFX} | tee -a ${CRONLOG})

# run
python test.py
```

And here are the contents of `test.py`:

```
import logging

def get_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger("testlog")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    lformat = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s"

    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(lformat))

    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = get_logger()
    logger.info("Should not appear in console but not cronlog.txt")
    logger.info("[BASH INFO] Should appear in both")
```

The `"[BASH INFO] Should appear in both"` message *does* successfully make it to the cron log, but the problem is that the first logging message is entirely omitted from the console output. How can I filter these messages such that those that pass through the `grep` make it to the console and the log while all others make it to the console only?

I know that this is the line that needs to change:

```
exec 2> >(grep ${LOGPFX} | tee -a ${CRONLOG})
```

Contents of `cronlog.txt`:

```
$ cat cronlog.txt 
2017-12-21 08:19:39,267 - INFO - test - <module> - [BASH INFO] Should appear in both
```

I've also tested this version of the bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGPFX="BASH"
CRONLOG="cronlog.txt"

ftee () {
    echo "I FOUND THIS: ${1}"
    echo "$1" >> ${CRONLOG}
}

exec 2> >(grep ${LOGPFX} | ftee) 2>&1

# run
python test.py
```

which properly directs everything to console, but does not write the proper message to the log (the `"I FOUND THIS: ${1}"` line prints an empty string)

Comment: `ftee` is obviously broken -- see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for guidance on reading from stdin, vs the command line (which it reads from now, despite nothing being passed on its command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `tee` write to another process substitution (which does the grep before writing) will do the trick:

```
# all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the shell
# don't use them for names you assign yourself.
logpfx="BASH"  # if a log msg has this term, put it in CRONLOG
cronlog="cronlog.txt"

exec 3>&2 # backup original stderr on FD 3
exec 2> >(tee -a >(grep "$logpfx" >"$cronlog"))
```

Note that *before* mailing the log, you should be sure to close the file descriptor and let it flush. Thus, after collecting the content you want to log and before sending email, you'll want to run:

```
exec 2>&3 # restore backup of original FD 3, so tee and grep can exit
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much

Comment: Should it be `2>&3` first (to back up stderr to another file descriptor) and then `3>&2` at the end? It seems backwards right now but that could be my own poor understanding.

Comment: `3>&2` makes FD 3 be a copy of FD 2. The inverse -- `2>&3` -- would be redirecting stderr (FD 2) at an FD 3 that isn't actually open.

Comment: Keep in mind that the direction of `<` or `>` determines whether to open the file or descriptor named on the right-hand side for read or for write (and whether the default, if no FD is given on the left, is `0` or `1` respectively). But which piece goes on the left or which piece goes on the right is constant.